# calculating % difference across grouped pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, calculation

I have calculated the difference between two months of values on grouped IDs in a dataframe, I now new to calculate the % difference but am receiving keyerrors or 'NaN' for all of my attempts using .pct_change().

My datafrane is constructed as below;

| ID | MONTH | TOTAL | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REF1 | 1 | 55 | 0 |
| REF1 | 2 | 65 | 10 |
| REF1 | 3 | 66 | 1 |
| REF2 | 7 | 65 | -15 |
| REF2 | 6 | 80 | 10 |
| REF2 | 8 | 100 | 35 |

I now need to add another column depicting the % Variance between the previous month.

```
    df_all = ( 
            pd.concat(pd.read_excel("testdata.xlsx",
                                    header=None, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
                .T.set_index(0).T
                .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
                .loc[:, ["ID", "DATE", "TOTAL"]]
                .assign(MONTH= lambda x: x["DATE"].dt.month)
                .groupby(by=["ID", "MONTH"], as_index=False).agg({"TOTAL":sum})
         )

df_all['Variance'] = df_all['TOTAL'].sub(
               df_all[['ID', 'MONTH']]
               .merge(df_all.assign(MONTH=df_all['MONTH'].add(1)),
                      how='left')['TOTAL']
              )
df_all['Variance'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: added my code for creation of dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pct_chaange` works just fine for given sample data:

```
df['%'] = df.sort_values(['ID','MONTH']).groupby(['ID'])['TOTAL'].pct_change() * 100
```

output :

```
     ID  MONTH  TOTAL  Variance          %
0  REF1      1     55         0        NaN
1  REF1      2     65        10  18.181818
2  REF1      3     66         1   1.538462
3  REF2      7     65       -15 -18.750000
4  REF2      6     80        10        NaN
5  REF2      8    100        35  53.846154
```

Comment: I need the code to group ID and MONTH so I would expect NaN for REF2/6 as no previous month data in the dataframe?

Comment: @Ryan1234 then group by id , see updated answer

Comment: thanks, just ran this code and I'm seeing 'ZeroDivisionError: division by zero'

Comment: @Ryan1234 hmm... you have 0 in `total` column which doesn't make sense for  comparison of percent change

Comment: a hack could be probably  replace it with a meaningful value  before calculating percentage change. but basically if you have 0 in total , so the percent change is infinity

Comment: another solution would be not to include those rows in your calculation

Comment: What could I insert into the code to not include where zero for the %? The zero is legitimate

Comment: I managed to make this work, thank you